# Layout quebrado para próxima medalha de tag

Tags: debate, bug, status-pronto, layout

A linha no layout do painel de reputação da página do usuário não está respondendo de acordo com o tamanho do texto, conforme podemos comparar:

**SOen**

[image: screenshot do SOen]

**SOpt**

[image: screenshot do SOpt]

Comment: [Isso tinha sido corrigido](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3762/separador-sobrepondo-r%C3%B3tulo-no-novo-perfil), ou pelo menos consta que tinha.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eita! E agora? Deixo a pergunta aí?

Comment: Deixa, porque na minha consta que foi corrigido, e a sua mostra um bug de regressão.

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Alinhamento do número de respostas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4009/3635)

Comment: Por que isso é relacionado, @GuilhermeNascimento?

Comment: É que os textos em Português "quebram" o layout @bfavaretto - Não é duplicata, mas é relacionado devido a isto.... eu acho :) Ou estou engando?

Comment: Ah, agora entendi. Faz sentido.

Comment: No site principal, como é que faz para se acompanhar o progresso em uma tag? Para mim, só dá para acompanhar isso no meta.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Só libera quando tiver completado todos os privilégios. Enquanto isso, você apenas acompanha o progresso dos privilégios.